# Adjusting SoapUI for simple REST web service

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, soapui

I have `REST` web service based on `Jersey` that runs on `TomCat 9` in my `Eclipse IDE`.

Server runs fine while test with broser:

openning link    http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages

brings:

```
<messages>
<message>
<author>koukushik</author>
<created>2019-02-20T12:48:41.817+02:00</created>
<id>1</id>
<message>Hello World</message>
</message>
<message>
<author>koukushik</author>
<created>2019-02-20T12:48:41.817+02:00</created>
<id>2</id>
<message>Hello Jersey</message>
</message>
</messages>
```

I'm trying to do the same in SoapUI 4.5.1:

I do:

```
New SoapUI project:
    project name: "pro1"
New REST Service
    Service name: "serv1"
    Service endpoint: http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages
New REST Resource
    Name resource1
    Resource Path/Endpoint http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages
New REST Method
    Method_1
    GET
```

Do request RAW:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/messenger/webapi/messages HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Answer HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>
      <title>HTTP Status 404  Not Found</title>
      <style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>HTTP Status 404  Not Found</h1>
      <hr class="line"/>
      <p>
         <b>Type</b>
         Status Report
      </p>
      <p>
         <b>Message</b>
         Not Found
      </p>
      <p>
         <b>Description</b>
         The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
      </p>
      <hr class="line"/>
      <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.14</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

Looks like GET method contains `HTTP/1.1` at the end. Is that problem? How to make `SoapUI` work with my project?

UPD

Works fine now:
[image]

Comment: Correct me if I understood wrong but in the RAW request I see that you are trying to access a different URL (http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages/messenger/webapi/messages) than your original  (http://localhost:8080/messenger/webapi/messages), which would lead to a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the URL you are trying to access as seen in the RAW request is not the one you want which as a result returns you a 404 status code

Please try the following settings

[image: settings]

Comment: Works fine now, but I don't see `Resource` and `Parameters` boxes in my request. How to enable them? I have updated question body with my request picture

Comment: Glad it works, which SoapUI version do you use? I use the 5.4.0, how do you proceed to make the request? Here is a good example from the official page of SoapUI https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/rest-resources-and-methods.html